# Ploting equation in R

Tags: r

I use this codes to solve a problem in R.  f(a)= |x|+5a-6, where |x|. will it be right to plot the value of merge. I am getting a straight line.

```
merge <- function(x) {
  y <- abs(a) + 5*(a)-6  
  return(y) 
}

merge (-4.534)

#c. Obtain the graph of the function.

plot (merge)
```

```
merge <- function(x) {
  y <- abs(a) + 5*(a)-6  
  return(y) 
}

merge (-4.534)

#c. Obtain the graph of the function.

plot (merge)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function has no value. You have to provide arguments. Try:

```
x <- seq(-100, 100)
merge <- function(a) {
  y <- abs(a) + 5*(a)-6  
  return(y) 
}
merge(x)
plot(x, merge(x))
```